# Trying to do an innter join in php with varibles in the select, but cant seem to get it to work

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell me what I might be going wrong? I've tried a few different things. But this is what I currently have.

```
$queryCurUser = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN '$ninenumber' ON users.ninenumber = '$ninenumber'.ninenumber"  ;
```

%ninenumber is a table and I need to use that variable so I can do something really cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the quotes with the backticks:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users
INNER JOIN
        `$ninenumber`
ON      users.ninenumber = `$ninenumber`.ninenumber
```